# CVS does not run properly as nonroot user

Tags: freebsd, root, cvs

I get an "rejected acces to DIR for user USER" message, when I try an "cvs login" to my local cvs... BUT everything works just fine, when cvs is set to run as root...

Im running FreeBSD 7.2, here is my config:

/etc/inetd.conf:

```
cvspserver  stream  tcp nowait  cvs(*)      /usr/libexec/tcpd   /usr/bin/cvs -f --allow-root /tmp/cvs_root pserver
```

(*) when I set it to root, everyting works just fine

/etc/passwd:

```
cvs:*:241:241:cvs Owner:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

/etc/group:

```
cvs:*:241:kriscom
```

kriscom's ENVIRONMENT:

```
CVSROOT=:pserver:kriscom@localhost:/tmp/cvs_root
```

and finally /tmp/cvs_root file permissons:

```
ls -alsn /tmp/cvs_root/
total 6
2 drwxr-xr-x   3 241  241   512 Aug 20 13:22 .
2 drwxrwxrwt  58 0    0    2048 Aug 20 13:31 ..
2 drwxrwxr-x   3 241  241  1024 Aug 20 13:22 CVSROOT
```

I did initialized the repository with

```
su cvs
cvs -d /tmp/cvs_root init
```

any ideas?
thanks in advance!

here is the nmap output

```
nmap -p cvspserver 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 5.50 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-08-22 17:50 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000094s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2401/tcp open  cvspserver

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.18 seconds
```

Comment: I think you are confusing it with module names/paths which are relative to CVS' root...

Answer (score 0):

It's better to not touch /etc/passwd and /etc/group manually, since they are not actually used by most userspace programs. Use [pw(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pw&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) (preferred) or [adduser(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=adduser&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).
Can you show `nmap -p csvpserver 127.0.0.1` output? If it shows that port is closed than `inetd` is just unable to resolve "cvs" username and start cvs and you need to add user with one of utils mentioned above.

Comment: oh... I think I did used pw at that time... If I didnt, would a reboot help?... see above for the nmap output... : )